# Div to span from left: 0 to certain point, regardless of screen width +CSS

Tags: css

I need to do something like this:
[image]

The black portion would be the page content.
1 and 2 are the divs I'm asking about.

What I need is that #1 goes from the beginning of the left portion of the screen to a fixed position, let's say 10px further to where the content begins.

Similar, #2 has to go from, say 10px before content ends, to the right portion of the screen.

Independently of the width of the screen. Preferably with position: absolute and floating divs, so as to not interfere with the design already in place.

Is it possible with CSS? Or will I have to resort to javascript?

Thank you!

Comment: so do you want three column layout, am i right? or something different with that?

Comment: No.. it's actually an existing page to which I need to add two floating divs. Announcements and stuff like that will be placed there.